# ko.js: Dynamically generated radio buttons and 'checked' dependent computations

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, radio-button

**tl;dr**: I use an ajax-retrieved array of objects to generate a list of radio buttons. When a radio button is *checked*, I want to make compute on the selected object and save the value inside a `ko.observable()` which is then shown in the HTML document via `data-bind`.

---

Here's what I did:

Firstly, I am retrieving array of user objects (via ajax):

```
var ViewModel = function() {

  var self = this;

  // an array of retrieved user objects
  self.retrievedUsers = ko.observableArray([]);

  self.getUsers = function() {
    $.getJSON('/retrieve-all-users', function(data) {
      self.retrievedUsers(data);
    });
  };
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

The retrieved array looks like this:

```
[{'name': 'Johnny', 'age': 20}, {'name': 'Jenny', 'age': 21}]
```

Then, I use this array to create radio buttons:

```
<form>
  <!-- ko foreach: retrievedUsers -->
  <input type="radio" name="people" data-bind="checkedValue: name">
  <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
  <!-- /ko -->
</form>
```

This should be rendered like this:

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="users" value="Johnny"> <span>Johnny</span>
  <input type="radio" name="users" value="Jenny"> <span>Jenny</span>
</form>
```

**Goal**: Whenever a radio button is checked (and a user is selected), I want to calculate the selected user's age in the upcoming year (user.age + 1) and save this computed age in an `ko.observable()`.

Then, I hope to `data-bind` the computed age in the template:

```
<div>
    The selected person will be 
    <span data-bind="text: SelectedPersonAgeNextYear"></span>
    years old in the upcoming year.
</div>
```

I appreciate any tips!

Another example usage: On a hotel booking website, a list of 'rooms' are shown as radio buttons. When a room is checked, a computed price is shown (price + tax + number of persons, etc).

Comment: A first look notice would be that self.retrievedUsers should be an observableArray instead of an observable.

Comment: I'm sure you can do this.  
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html
I will try to come up with an answer.  a fiddle would be nice, otherwise i will setup a local test with your example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vt6v6L9u/2/

html:

```
<form>
    <div data-bind="foreach: retrievedUsers">
        <div>
            <label data-bind="attr:{for:$index}">
                <input type="radio" name="people2" data-bind="attr: {id: $index,value: age}, checked: $root.selected" />
                <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<div>
    The selected person will be
    <span data-bind="text: SelectedPersonAgeNextYear"></span>
    years old in the upcoming year.
</div>
<button data-bind="click: getUsers">get users</button>
```

javascript:

```
var ViewModel = function () {

    var self = this;
    // an array of retrieved user objects
    self.retrievedUsers = ko.observable([]);

    self.getUsers = function () {
        self.retrievedUsers([{ 'name': 'Johnny', 'age': 20 }, { 'name': 'Jenny', 'age': 21 }]);
    };

    self.selected = ko.observable();
    self.SelectedPersonAgeNextYear = ko.computed(function () {
        return parseInt(self.selected(), 10) + 1;
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: Hi @Nate, thank you for the answer. This solution almost works! It looks like when a radio button is clicked, it is not 'checked'.

Comment: yeah i noticed that, I will try to fix that

Comment: It looks like the click binding is causing the problem -- it seems to have prevented the `checked` and `checkedValue` bindings from activating, for reasons unknown to me. I've tried experimenting but the radio buttons remained unchecked even though it functions exactly as wanted. It would be great if the input labels were also to be included in the click binding.

Comment: I updated the html to have the names clickable as well.  I'm still not sure why the radio is not checked.

Comment: ok, try the new fiddle link, it should work as you want it now

Comment: Wow, good thinking Nate! Thank you so much. I learned something new from the usage of `$index` there. Is there a way to concat a string and the `$index` to make a new id? For example: instead of `<label for="1">`, we can use `option_1`.

Comment: I think I did that at one time, let me check, I'm sure you can

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70882/discussion-between-nate-and-haopei).