# concatenating a string to $index in foreach loop knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

This is a connected to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28488524/ko-js-dynamically-generated-radio-buttons-and-checked-dependent-computations)

The following works..http://jsfiddle.net/vt6v6L9u/2/

```
<div data-bind="foreach: retrievedUsers" >
    <div>
        <label data-bind="attr:{for:$index}">
```

I need to concatenate a string to $index.. http://jsfiddle.net/vt6v6L9u/4/

```
<div data-bind="foreach: retrievedUsers" >
    <div>
        <label data-bind="attr:{for:'const' + $index}">
```

The fiddle seems to work but if you inspect the radio button element..
you find..

```
<label data-bind="attr:{for:'const' + $index}" for="constfunction c(){if(0<arguments.length)return c.equalityComparer&amp;&amp;c.equalityComparer(d,arguments[0])||(c.O(),d=arguments[0],c.N()),this;a.i.lb(c);return d}">
```

Any help is sincerely appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$index` is itself observable and must be evaluated:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: retrievedUsers" >
    <div>
        <label data-bind="attr:{for:'const' + $index()}">
```

(note the parens)

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vt6v6L9u/5/